# SilverStripe 3.4 Custom Reports - Set filenames as links in custom report to allow for easy editing

Tags: reporting, silverstripe

I'm new to SilverStripe reports but I haven't been able to find anything related to this particular issue so far.

I have a custom report that lists all images and files on the site in a gridview, however, I would like to make it so that people can either click on the filename and go to the image or file to edit it, or have an edit button for each image and file. Right now, if anyone wants to edit a file or image, they have to leave the report, go the Files tab, search for said file/image, and click to edit. That's rather tedious.

I know there is a way to make page titles clickable in reports based on the existing report examples in cms/code/reports. But I don't see anything that relates to linking to uploaded images and files.

Is there is a way to do this?

Here is the code for my custom report:

```
<?php

class CustomSideReport_ListofImagesAndFiles extends SS_Report {

    // the name of the report
    public function title() {
        return 'All Images and Files';
    }

    // what we want the report to return
    public function sourceRecords($params = null)
    {
        return File::get()
            ->sort('Title');
    }

    // which fields on that object we want to show
    public function columns() {
        return array(
            "Title" => 'Image Title',
            'Filename' => array(
                "Filename" => "Filename",
                "link" => true,
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

using `"link" => true` doesn't work -- it tries to create a page link, which isn't right. I've tried "edit" and "CanEdit."

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I came up with this from referencing the setup for the Broken Links report:

```
// which fields on that object we want to show
public function columns()
{
    $linkBase = singleton('CMSFileAddController')->Link('EditForm/field/File/item');
    $linkBaseEditLink = str_replace("/add","",$linkBase);
    $fields = array(
        'Title' => 'Title',
        'AbsoluteLink' => array(
            'title' => _t('CustomSideReport_ListofImagesAndFiles.ColumnFilename', 'Filename'),
            'formatting' => function($value, $item) use ($linkBaseEditLink) {
                return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    Controller::join_links($linkBaseEditLink, $item->ID."/edit"),
                    strstr($value, '/assets/', false)
                );
            }
        )
    );

   return $fields;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution ever--it works, and I can't find anything else that relates to this kind of report creation for SilverStripe (everything I've found deals with getting `Pages` for reports, not images or files.

I had to make some tweaks because there is no `CMSFileEditController` like there is a `CMSPageEditController,` but I made due with what I had.

If anyone has a better solution then by all means, please share!